# Fetching Azure Costs with Powershell and REST-API

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to use REST to retrieve my Costs from the [Azure API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?tabs=HTTP).

```
https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/$BillingAccountId/providers/Microsoft.CostManagement/query?api-version=2022-10-01
```

I get the column headers as property Colums,

```
name              type
----              ----
Cost              Number
UsageDate         Number
ResourceId        String
ResourceType      String
ResourceLocation  String
ChargeType        String
ResourceGroupName String
SubscriptionName  String
PublisherType     String
ServiceName       String
ServiceTier       String
Meter             String
Currency          String
```

the data as property Rows:

[image]

The number of columns is always 13, but the data sets in the rows can vary. I.e. instead of 13 data records, there may be 12 or 10. How do I get the correct data records assigned to the correct columns again (e.g as a hashtable)?

All my attempts have failed so far because I cannot recognise programmatically which data contents are missing.

**Correct Response:**

```
Cost              : 0
UsageDate         : 20231012
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/***/resourcegroups/networkwatcherrg/providers/microsoft.network/networkwatchers/networkwatcher_westeurope
ResourceType      : microsoft.network/networkwatchers
ResourceLocation  : ***
ChargeType        : Usage
ResourceGroupName : networkwatcherrg
SubscriptionName  : ***
PublisherType     : Azure
ServiceName       : Network Watcher
ServiceTier       : Network Watcher
Meter             : Standard Network Logs Collected
Currency          : EUR
```

**Incorrect response (because some data are missing)**

```
Cost              : 0
UsageDate         : 68004
ResourceId        : 20231012
ResourceType      : /subscriptions/***/providers/microsoft.security/pricings/virtualmachines
ResourceLocation  : microsoft.security/pricings
ChargeType        : Unknown
ResourceGroupName : Usage
SubscriptionName  :
PublisherType     : ***
ServiceName       : Azure
ServiceTier       : Security Center
Meter             : Microsoft Def for Servers
Currency          : Standard P1 Node
```

Comment: Can you show the raw “columns” json, and the json for a working “row” (anonymised if need be) and the json for a not-working “row” as well. It looks like you’re doing some processing of the response as well to convert it into a name-value pair structure (either a hashtable or pscustomobject) to get the output you’ve listed - can you show that code also.

Comment: And since the results are paginated, are you processing the “columns” header for each page, in case they’re different per page?